# Graph API Unable to read JSON request payload

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, httprequest, power-automate

In power automate using Invoke an HTTP request, I am unable to make a graph API call for email sent(Post: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail) with a customized email body (HTML elements and tags). It does not allow the below custom HTML code and errors as "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure the Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format."  Please find the code below. In addition, HTML code is

Please find the code below.
[image]

And HTML Code is
[image]

Comment: PowerAutomate desktop?  That's not desktop, are you sure.  Also, can you not use the standard send email connector?

Comment: Not for desktop, any format for email connector for custom email body

Comment: Ok but you said PowerAutomate desktop.

Comment: Can you please refer to this example:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-send-a-new-email-using-json-format

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your payload is not in a valid json format. You have to escape the quotation marks. Use `\"` intead of `"`.

```json
{
   "data": "<html><head>The title attribute example</head><body><h3 title=\"Hello HTML!\">Titled head tag example</h3></body></html>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Optimal already mentioned. It is good to escape the quotation marks of the HTML Body value.

However, I see the request body also has a [saveToSentItems boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) property. Can you try it with that boolean as well?

Try something like below:

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "@{triggerBody()['text']}",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "HTML",
      "content": "@{triggerBody()['text_1']}"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "@{triggerBody()['text_2']}"
        }
      }
    ]
    },
  "saveToSentItems": "true"
}
```